# Gradle: Substitute a library when running tests

Tags: android, gradle

**Usecase**

I'm building a library and it depends on `rxjava`.

Since rxjava is large, I decided to minify it using proguard and make another module called `:custom_rx`.

---

**Problem**

Since `.test()` method of RxJava does not need to be at the release, I removed tests for the minified module. However, **tests will not pass**.

---

**Question**

Since `test` task and `release` tasks are different, I can tell gradle to use non-modified RxJava for test tasks.

**How can I replace a library to another, only when gradle is running tests?**

---

**Code I've tried**

I used this code to substitute the library on test. But tests still fail:

```
subprojects {
    project.configurations.all { config ->
        if (config.name.contains("test") || config.name.contains("Test")) {
            resolutionStrategy.dependencySubstitution {
                substitute project(":custom_rx") because "we use a non-minified rxjava for tests" with module("io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:$versions.rxJava")
            }
        }
    }
}
```